# "symbol not found" in C codes of makefile project in xcode

Tags: c, makefile, xcode4.5

I create a makefile project in xcode4.5 (OSX -> Other -> External Build System) and add some `c` files into it. And I can `make` the project successfully.

But it tells me `"symbol not found"` when I try to jump to the definition of a function.

I try some ways from google, such as delete the xcworkspace and xcuserdata folders and delete derived data of project and so on. But all they fail. Any solutions?

BTW, my project is very simple and locates [here](https://github.com/changchang/helloworld).

Answer (score 1):

- Makefile and code works fine commandline.
- Setup a quick project in xcode (5.1.1 btw, it's what I have
  installed)
- OSX->Other->External Build System
- Set the project directory to the git checkout in the project creation
  wizard.
- In the External Build Tool Configuration->Info, set the Directory to
  the git checkout directory.
- Product->Build
- Builds fine, runs fine.

Nothing more can be done to help if there isn't a something in the steps I took that helps, would have to look at a dmg of your xcode project.